An application of Krein-Milman Theorem
A corollary of Krein-Milman Theorem states the following : If $H$ is a locally convex topological vector space, $K$ is a compact convex subset of $H$ and $F \subset K$ such that  $K$ is the closure of the convex hull of $F$, then the set of extreme points of $K$ are in $\bar F \\$.
Now suppose that $G$ is a locally compact topological group and $\hat G$ be the set of equivalence classes of irreducible unitary representations of $G$. We fix a $\pi_0 \in \hat G$. Let $\phi_0$ be a normalised function of positive type associated to $\pi_0$. Suppose that $\phi_0$ can be approximated uniformly on compact subsets of $G$ by a convex combination of normalised functions of positive type associated to unitary representations in $\hat G - \{\pi_0\}$. We need to apply the above theorem to prove that $\phi_0$ can be approximated uniformly on compact subsets of $G$ by a function of positive type associated to a unitary representation in $\hat G - \{\pi_0\}\\$.
I thought of taking $F$ to be the set of normalised functions of positive type associated to unitary representations in $\hat G - \{\pi_0\}$ and $K$ to be the closure of the convex hull of $F$ in the weak* topology of $L^{\infty} (G)$. How do I proceed further? Am I on the right track?
